# Joining tables dynamically with pure LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following scenario:

1. There can be two random tables with over 100 columns each.
2. One of the tables has a foreign key to another.
3. A user selects a set of columns from both tables, which we should select from db and send back as a JSON object. The restriction is that it should be pure LINQ (not DynamicLINQ).

I tried to play around with expressions by the answers I could find, but the best I've achieved is IEnumerable as result, which is unacceptable, because I need IQueriable to filter it later. I was searching back and forth, but the only working variant I found was on DynamicSQL [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fdba5462-bfc4-4c2c-848f-f5eb6bebc384/dynamically-query-across-multiple-tables), but I'm not allowed to use it.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Update: As an example, I have two random tables joined by fk, so it's just a regular join, like `from t1 in Table1 join t2 in Table2 on t1.field1 = t2.field2`. All I need is to be able to pass select expression to this join, built based on collection of strings containing columns I want to select, for example, if I have `{"t1.field1", "t1.field2", "t2.field3"}`, then the join should look like `from t1 in Table1 join t2 in Table2 on t1.field1 = t2.field2 select new {t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.field3}`.

Comment: Write your join in db as view. And map this view to your entities.

Comment: @user1681317, as I said, there will be random tables with random set of columns, so I need dynamic join with anonymous type in select. I'm pretty positive this can be achieved with the help of expressions, but my knowledge in this topic is not perfect and I couldn't manage to implement this

Comment: Could you please elaborate on you query. It would help a lot if you would provide your actual query and tell us which parts you want to dynamizise (is this a word?).

Comment: @Sefe, sure, but the query is trivial: table1.Join(table2, <dynamicSelector1>, <dynamicSelector2>, <dynamicSelectQuery>). The most important part is dynamicSelectQuery, which has to return an anonymous object

Comment: Can you please provide a _concrete_ example without placeholders and add it to you question. It would be good to also show the expressions you have tried already.

Comment: @Sefe, what's wrong with placeholders? As I said, It can be any random pair of tables. As for expressions I've tried - my main problem is that I don't know how to generate and pass select expression like (t,p) => new {...} inside the join. If I solve this, the task can be considered to be done, it's the main thing.

Comment: How are we supposed to help with an expression if all we have is <placeholder>? This is the most important part.

Comment: @Sefe, maybe I didn't explain clearly, if so, I'm sorry. I have two random tables joined by fk, so it's just a regular join, like from t1 in Table1 join t2 in Table2 on t1.field1 = t2.field2. All i need is to be able to pass select expression to this join, built based on collection of strings containing columns I want to select, for example, if I have {"t1.field1", "t1.field2", "t2.field3"}, then the join should look like : from t1 in Table1 join t2 in Table2 on t1.field1 = t2.field2 select new {t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.field3}

Comment: It would be good if you could update your question accordingly, so the answers are in context.

Comment: @Sefe, Added the example

Comment: So you want to re-implement DynamicLINQ?

Comment: @RobertMcKee, yes, what I actually need is ParseLambla implementation of DynamicLinq. I would gladly use DynamicLinq, but it's not allowed in task scope.

Comment: Well DynamicLINQ is about 2500 lines of code.  At 50 lines of code (Write, test, debug) per day, is 10 weeks of work in the task scope to recreate it?  More than clicking include from NuGet?

Comment: @RobertMcKee, it's not my requirement, that's what I have to deal with. I don't need reworking dynamic linq, I need just dynamic join select statement built with expressions

Comment: Where does this restriction come from? I don't understand why you wouldn't use DLINQ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with creating instances from a list of columns is that, since .NET is type safe, you will need a type that you can instantiate. When you use anonymous classes (i.e. the `new` keyword without a class name), the compiler will create a class for you. It's anonymous, but it's still there *at compile time* (you can check this in a decompiler of yout choice).

If you want to truly be fully dynamic *at runtime* you will have to dynamically create and compile your classes at execution time. For that you might want to look into the `System.CodeDom` and the `System.Reflection.Emit`namespaces, that both contain classes that allow you to dynamically create types at runtime. That, however, will be quite a massive undertaking, which it doubt will be worth your time. And then you want to access the data in these objects, so you'll probably have to go for `dynamic` variables.

What should be more feasible is to create a regular class at compile time and instantiate it in your LINQ query. This class would contain *all* possible properties that you can set. When you instantiate it, you don't have to fill all the fields.

Once you have your class, you can dynamically create expressions that will instantiate it. That's what the classes in the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace are for. The `Expression` class contains factory methods that allow you to create the expression tree you need.

To create your expression tree, you first have to decompose the expression you want to model. Yor expression for the `Join` would look similar to this (assuming your container class is named `DataContainer`):

```
(t1, t2) => new DataContainer {
    Value1 = t1.field1,
    Value2 = t1.field2,
    Value3 = t2.field3
}
```

This expression has to be split in its parts according to their precedence:

- The lambda expression initiated by the lambda operator `=>`: `LambdaExpression`, created by `Expression.Lambda`
- The parameters `t1` and `t2` to the left of the lambda operator: `ParameterExpression`, created with `Expression.Parameter`
- The object instantiation `new DataContainer` to the right of the lambda operator: `NewExpression`, created with `Expression.New`
- The assignments within the initialization block initiated by `=`: `BinaryExpression`, created with `Expression.Assign`
- The properties to the left of the assignment: `MemberExpression`, created with `Expression.Property`
- The property dereferencing with `.field1`: `MemberExpression`, created with `Expression.Property`
- The parameter access `t1`: `ParameterExpression`, created with `Expression.Parameter` (but you are reusing the parameter expression you created for the lambda expression)

As you can see, this is quite tedious as compared to just writing down the expression (or using Dynamic LINQ). I will exemplify this with the sub-expression `t1.field1`:

At this point you will have created the `t1` parameter for the left side of the lambda:

```
ParameterExpression t1Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Table1), "t1");
```

Which you reuse for your property access:

```
MemberExpression t1field1Property = Expression.Property(t1Param, "field1");
```

This expression you yan use when you create your assignment, which you will use along with the other assignments in the instantiation expression, which you will use for the right side of your lamdba expression, along with the other needed expressions. You can also write this as a single tree (with the exception of the parameter expressions you are going to reuse).

Happy coding!